# How to convert lazy sequence to non-lazy in Clojure

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

I tried the following in Clojure, expecting to have the class of a non-lazy sequence returned:

```
(.getClass (doall (take 3 (repeatedly rand))))
```

However, this still returns `clojure.lang.LazySeq`.  My guess is that `doall` does evaluate the entire sequence, but returns the original sequence as it's still useful for memoization.

So what is the idiomatic means of creating a non-lazy sequence from a lazy one?

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has asked why you are concerned about the actual type of the return value of `doall`

Comment: You could convert to a vector: `(vec (take 3 (repeatedly rand)))`

Answer (score 181, accepted):

`doall` is all you need. Just because the seq has type LazySeq doesn't mean it has pending evaluation. Lazy seqs cache their results, so all you need to do is walk the lazy seq once (as `doall` does) in order to force it all, and thus render it non-lazy. `seq` does *not* force the entire collection to be evaluated.

Comment: I've changed this to the accepted answer.  On a related note, by what means can you determine if a LazySeq has previously been evaluated?

Comment: I believe you just call `realized?`.

Comment: There should probably be a `realize` operation to match `realized?`.

Comment: This is all very nice. But since some functions like `contains?` don't care whether you realized the lazy seq or not, this answers to the specific question as asked, but less so to the title of the question.

Answer (score 85):

This is to some degree a question of taxonomy. **a lazy sequence is just one type of sequence** as is a list, vector or map. So the answer is of course "it depends on what type of non lazy sequence you want to get:
Take your pick from:

- an ex-lazy (fully evaluated) lazy sequence  `(doall ... )`
- a list for sequential access  `(apply list (my-lazy-seq)) OR (into () ...)`
- a vector for later random access `(vec (my-lazy-seq))`
- a map or a set if you have some special purpose.

You can have whatever type of sequence most suites your needs.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: The accepted answer is technically correct, but this answer was most useful to me.  I was trying to map a function over a vector and then spit the results to a file, and even after calling doall, the file contained "clojure.lang.LazySeq@address" instead of the contents of the sequence.  Calling vec on value map returned got me what I needed to spit out to the file.

Comment: @JesseRosalia It's good to know that the one and only Rich Hickey response in all of SO was  was technically correct.  ;-)

Comment: `(vec (my-lazy-seq))` is not so nice in situations like the following: 
`(vec (json/parse-string "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"))
;; => [["foo" "bar"]]`
Since `cheshire` chooses to produce a lazy-seq from `(json/parse-string)`

Comment: Mitigation for the above was to use eager `(json/parse-string-strict)`

Answer (score 25):

This Rich guy seems to know his clojure and is absolutely right.
Buth I think this code-snippet, using your example,  might be a useful complement to this question :

```
=> (realized? (take 3 (repeatedly rand))) 
false
=> (realized? (doall (take 3 (repeatedly rand)))) 
true
```

Indeed *type* has not changed but *realization* has

Comment: It's worth noting, though, that you don't need to force the entire sequence for `realized?` to return `true`.  E.g. `(let [r (range) r? (realized? r)] (doall (take 1 r)) [r? (realized? r)]) => [false true]`

Comment: This Rich guy :D haha

Comment: @nimrod :) the pun however was meant to be in "hís clojure".

Comment: For those who don't know, "the Rich guy" invented Clojure.

Comment: @AlexCoventry your example returns `[true true]`

Comment: Huh, the behavior must have changed since I wrote that comment.

Answer (score 8):

I stumbled on this this [blog](http://www.pawfal.org/dave/blog/2011/06/un-lazy-fying-clojure/) post about `doall` not being recursive. For that I found the first comment in the post did the trick. Something along the lines of:

```
(use 'clojure.walk)
(postwalk identity nested-lazy-thing)
```

I found this useful in a unit test where I wanted to force evaluation of some nested applications of `map` to force an error condition.

Answer (score 5):

```
(.getClass (into '() (take 3 (repeatedly rand))))
```

Comment: This is a terrible idea. It reverses the input seq.

Comment: Of course, in this case reversing the input makes no difference, since they are just 3 random numbers.... :-)