# How to get a collection of return values from a function with side effects?

Tags: clojure

Looking for a way to generate a collection of return values from a function with side effects, so that I could feed it to `take-while`.

```
(defn function-with-side-effects [n]
  (if (> n 10) false (do (perform-io n) true)))

(defn call-function-with-side-effects []
  (take-while true (? (iterate inc 0) ?)))
```

UPDATE

Here is what I have after Jan's answer:

```
(defn function-with-side-effects [n]
  (if (> n 10) false (do (println n) true)))

(defn call-function-with-side-effects []
  (take-while true? (map function-with-side-effects (iterate inc 0))))

(deftest test-function-with-side-effects
  (call-function-with-side-effects))
```

Running the test doesn't print anything. Using `doall` results in out of memory exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shouldn't a `map` solve the problem?

```
(defn call-function-with-side-effects []
  (take-while true? (map function-with-side-effects (iterate inc 0))))
```

If you want all side effects to take effect use [`doall`](http://www.clodoc.org/doc/clojure.core/doall). Related: [How to convert lazy sequence to non-lazy in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641626/how-to-covert-a-lazy-sequence-to-a-non-lazy-in-clojure).

```
(defn call-function-with-side-effects []
  (doall (take-while true? (map function-with-side-effects (iterate inc 0)))))
```

Mind that I replaced the `true` in the second line with [`true?`](http://www.clodoc.org/doc/clojure.core/true%3F) assuming that this was what you meant.

Comment: Jan, I would appreciate a comment on the updated section of the question. Thanks!

Comment: Yuriy, good point, I should have explicitly state where the `doall` should go. I've revised the answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Got it, great! Thank you for helping a Clojure noob!

Comment: More than happy to help, mate.