# List of a..b in clojure

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, I can have a sequence `a..b` with `(range a b)`. But this is a lazy sequence as I understand. Can I just generate a list and/or vector of numbers `a..b`?

Note: I am new to Clojure.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641626/.  Do you want a *non-lazy* vector?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't think that is a duplicate of this. This question seems broader in scope because it references converting between types as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

do you mean something like

```
user>  (vec (range 2 7))
[2 3 4 5 6]
user> (apply list (range 2 7))
(2 3 4 5 6)
user> (into [] (range 2 7))
[2 3 4 5 6]
user> (into '() (range 2 7))
(6 5 4 3 2) ; <-- note the order
user> (into #{} (range 2 7))
#{2 3 4 5 6}
```

Comment: Thank you for different approaches!