# Executing a lazy sequence of functions

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

I'm wondering how to force a lazy sequence of functions to be evaluated.

For example if I have a function that returns the integer 1:

```
test.core=> (fn [] 1)
#<core$eval2480$fn__2481 test.core$eval2480$fn__2481@4163c61>
test.core=> ((fn [] 1))
1
```

And I construct a lazy sequence of these functions:

```
test.core=> (repeat 5 (fn [] 1))
(#<core$eval2488$fn__2489 test.core$eval2488$fn__2489@76fd6301> ...)

test.core=> (class (repeat 5 '(fn [] 1)))
clojure.lang.LazySeq
```

How do I actually execute the functions in the sequence?

```
test.core=> (take 1 (repeat 5 (fn [] 1)))
(#<core$eval2492$fn__2493 test.core$eval2492$fn__2493@46e1e0c8>)

test.core=> (take 1 (repeat 5 '(fn [] 1)))
((fn [] 1))

test.core=> ((take 1 (repeat 5 '(fn [] 1))))

ClassCastException clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

I've read through [How to convert lazy sequence to non-lazy in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641626/how-to-convert-lazy-sequence-to-non-lazy-in-clojure) , which suggested doall...but I'm not sure where the results are going?  I'm expecting [1 1 1 1 1] or something similar.

```
test.core=> (doall (repeat 5 (fn [] 1)))
(#<core$eval2500$fn__2501 test.core$eval2500$fn__2501@14e3c50c>...)

test.core=> (realized? (doall (repeat 5 (fn [] 1))))
true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are returning a sequence of un-evaluated functions. You can evaluate them as follows:

```
=> (map #(%) (repeat 5 (fn [] 1)))
(1 1 1 1 1)
```

Both `map` and `repeat` are lazy, but the REPL or any other consumer forces the evaluation of at least as much of a lazy sequence as it needs.

Comment: And it's worth noting that sequence chunking will cause them to be evaluated in chunks of 32

Comment: Only for a function which produces chunked sequences (which `repeat` does not). Chunking matters occasionally, but it can safely be ignored until long after OP has figured out how to invoke a list of functions.